# Almost sure and expectation. How are they exactly related?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value, almost-everywhere

I know that for a general random variable $X$ (defined on some probability space) it holds true that $\mathbb{P}(X<\infty)=1$ **implies** that $\mathbb{E}(X)<\infty$ (and I already know how to prove this).

On the other hand, if
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{E}(X)<\infty
\end{equation*}
does it follow that
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{P}(X<\infty)=1
\end{equation*}
(i.e. $X<\infty$ a.s.)?
If so, how can one prove that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it is not true that $P(X<\infty)=1$ implies $E(X)<\infty$, and you should find a counterexample to that assertion. On the other hand, the converse is true. The reason is: If $P(|X|=\infty)>0$ then $$E(|X|)\ge E(|X|I(|X|=\infty))=\infty\cdot P(|X|=\infty)=\infty.$$

Another proof uses Markov's inequality. If $E(|X|)<\infty$ then
$$P(|X|>M)\le \frac{E|X|}M
$$ so by continuity from above
$$P(|X|=\infty) = P\left(\bigcap_M \{|X|>M\}\right)=\lim_M P(|X|>M)=0.$$

Comment: Probably I have not understood your answer correctly. What I can understand is that, contrarily to what I state in my question, $P(X<\infty)=1$ **does not necessarily imply** that $E(X)<\infty$, while $\mathbb{P}(|X|=\infty)>0$ **implies** that $\mathbb{E}(|X|)=\infty$. Now, what can one say about the opposite, that is *about whether $\mathbb{E}(X)<\infty$ implies that $\mathbb{P}(X<\infty)=1$?* @grand_chat

Comment: Thank you for your editing, now it is clear as to that aspect. Last two questions/observations:

1) is Pareto distribution with parameter $\alpha\leq1$ a good counterexample to show that $\mathbb{P}(X<\infty)=1$ **does not necessarily imply** that $\mathbb{E}(X)<\infty$?


2) am I right if I state that instead $P(X= Y)=1 \Rightarrow E(X)= E(Y)$ and $P(X > Y)=1 \Rightarrow E(X) > E(Y)$? (that is, only $P(X \leq Y)=1 \Rightarrow E(X) > E(Y)$ does not hold true)? @grand_chat

Comment: @Strictly_increasing Correct, the fact $P(X<\infty)=1$ does not necessarily imply $E(X)<\infty$. My answer proves the converse by proving the contrapositive, and the second answer proves it directly

Comment: @Strictly_increasing (1) correct! (2) It is true that $P(X\ge Y)=1$ implies $E(X)\ge E(Y)$ assuming the expectations exist. [Reason: If $W$ is nonnegative almost surely then $E(W)\ge0$.] So if $P(X\le Y)=1$ you can conclude $E(X)\le E(Y)$.

Comment: Oh, right! Hence, the **only case in which I cannot state that $\mathbb{P}(X\leq Y) = 1$ $\Rightarrow$ $\mathbb{E}(X)\leq\mathbb{E}(Y)$** is when $Y=\infty$, isn't it?
Sorry for all these questions and thank you infinitely for your kindness and patience @grand_chat

Comment: @Strictly_increasing You are welcome. If $X\le Y$ then $E(Y-X)\ge 0$ is true always . If $E(X)$ and $E(Y)$ exist, then you can further conclude $E(Y)\ge E(X)$ (by linearity).

Comment: OK, so...the statement "if $X \leq Y$ then $\mathbb{E}(Y-X) \geq 0$ is true **always**" would imply that also in the case in which $Y=\infty$ I could state that $\mathbb{P}(X<Y=\infty)=1$ implies $\mathbb{E}(X)<\mathbb{E}(Y)=\infty$, but, as previously seen, there are counterexamples proving that $\mathbb{P}(X<Y=\infty)=1$ **does not necessarily imply** $\mathbb{E}(X)<\mathbb{E}(Y)=\infty$. How can such facts cohexist?

Comment: @Strictly_increasing  Notice I am using $\le $ not $<$.  If $P(X<\infty)=1$ the conclusion is that $E(X)\le\infty$, not that $E(X)<\infty$. So there is no contradiction.

Comment: Sorry for my confusion, now I finally get it!!! Thank you a lot once again, your help has been precious to me :)  @grand_chat